# Aggregating a unique pair of column values from the same table based on a common column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I have the following table:

```
my_table
------------------------
| common_id | uniq_val |
------------------------
|    1      |    foo   |          
------------------------
|    1      |    bar   |          
------------------------
```

And I want to aggregate values from it such that the resulting query looks like:

```
DESIRED RESULT
---------------------------------------
| common_id | uniq_val_1 | uniq_val_2 |
---------------------------------------
|    1      |     foo    |      bar   |
---------------------------------------

OR

---------------------------------------
| common_id | uniq_val_1 | uniq_val_2 |
---------------------------------------
|    1      |     bar    |      foo   |
---------------------------------------
```

So I've written the query:

```
SELECT t1.common_id, t1.uniq_val, t2.uniq_val
FROM my_table t1 JOIN my_table AS t2 
ON t1.common_id=t2.common_id 
WHERE t1.uniq_val!=t2.uniq_val;
```

Which results in

```
RESULTING SELECT
---------------------------------------
| common_id | uniq_val_1 | uniq_val_2 |
---------------------------------------
|    1      |     foo    |      foo   |
---------------------------------------
|    1      |     bar    |      bar   |
---------------------------------------
```

But I only need one of those columns, so I should be able to do a GROUP BY t1.common_id, like:

```
SELECT t1.common_id, t1.uniq_val, t2.uniq_val
FROM my_table t1 JOIN my_table AS t2 
ON t1.common_id=t2.common_id 
WHERE t1.uniq_val!=t2.uniq_val
GROUP BY t1.common_id;
```

Unfortunately this returns the error:

```
ERROR:  column "t1.uniq_val" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Can anyone point out the error in my logic?

Comment: Will each common_id value always have just 2 unique values? Could some have 2, others have 3 or 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simple aggregation?

```
select common_id, min(uniq_val) as uniq_val_1, max(uniq_val) as uniq_val_2
from my_table
group by common_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `distinct on`

`SELECT distinct on (t1.common_id) t1.common_id, t1.uniq_val, t2.uniq_val
FROM my_table t1 JOIN my_table AS t2 
ON t1.common_id=t2.common_id 
WHERE t1.uniq_val!=t2.uniq_val;`

I think it will produce what you need!

Comment: gives ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," Are you sure that works for postgres?

Comment: I just used your query, the one you said was working and added `distinct on (t1.common_id)`. Notice that there is no comma between this and the first field you select  (t1.common_id)!

Answer (score 0):

This will handle up to 10 uniq_val values per common_id. You can remove or add to account for fewer or more uniq_val values if needed.

See a demonstration here with common_id values that have varying counts of uniq_val values:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e2c87/1/0

```
select common_id,
       max(case when rn = 1 then uniq_val else null end) as uniq_val_1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then uniq_val else null end) as uniq_val_2,
       max(case when rn = 3 then uniq_val else null end) as uniq_val_3,
       max(case when rn = 4 then uniq_val else null end) as uniq_val_4,
       max(case when rn = 5 then uniq_val else null end) as uniq_val_5,
       max(case when rn = 6 then uniq_val else null end) as uniq_val_6,
       max(case when rn = 7 then uniq_val else null end) as uniq_val_7,
       max(case when rn = 8 then uniq_val else null end) as uniq_val_8,
       max(case when rn = 9 then uniq_val else null end) as uniq_val_9,
       max(case when rn = 10 then uniq_val else null end) as uniq_val_10
from(
select row_number() over (partition by common_id order by common_id, uniq_val) as rn,
       common_id,
       uniq_val
  from my_table
 order by common_id, uniq_val) x
 group by common_id
 order by common_id
```